# Segfault when using invalid input

Tags: c, unix, segmentation-fault

I'm getting a segfault thrown when using invalid input or the `-help` flag in the command arguments.  It is a re-creation of the Unix `expand` utility, and its supposed to handle errors in a similar fashion.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  char help1[]= "-help";
  char help2[]= "--help";

  int spaces; //number of spaces to replace tabs

  if (argc==1){ //if only one argument in stack

    //check if asking for help
    if ( (strcmp(argv[1], help1)==0) || (strcmp(argv[1], help2)==0) )
      printHelp(); 

    else
      printError(); //otherwise, print error message    

    //right number of tokens are provided, need to validate them
    } else if (argc>=2){
      spaces= atoi(argv[2]); //assign it to spaces

      parse_file(spaces); //open the stream and pass on
  }     
  return 0;

}
```

My printerror method:

```
void printError(){
  fprintf(stderr, "\nInvalid Input.\n");
  fprintf(stderr, "The proper format is myexpand -[OPTION] [NUMBER OF SPACES]\n");
  exit(1);
}
```

When I try invalid input or the help flag, I get a segfault.  Why is this, since I'm checking if the first flag is help?

Comment: Haven't done any C for a while, but aren't arguments 0 indexed?  strcmp(argv[1]... should be strcmp(argv[0] and so on?

Comment: No, argv[0] is the name of your executable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a single command-line parameter is passed to your program, `argc == 2`, so you need to replace

```
if (argc==1){ //if only one argument in stack
```

with

```
if (argc==2){
```

Note that in most systems `argv[0]` is the program name and in this case `argc` is at least 1. You can think of `argc` as the number of elements in `argv`. If you’re testing for `argv[1]`, you’re expecting `argv` to have at least two elements (`argv[0]` and `argv[1]`), hence `argc` needs to be at least 2.

Comment: That was it, thanks.  I had made some changes later on in the code, and those changes needed to be reflected in the argc test.

Answer (score 3):

`argv[0]` counts too, so if `argc==1` `argv[1]` is `NULL`

Your help message should be displayed if there are less than 2 parameter given, hence

```
if (argc<3)
    printHelp();
else if(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Upon initialization, the arguments to main will meet the following requirements according to [this](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter10/arguments_to_main.html).

- `argc` is greater than zero.
- `argv[argc]` is a null pointer.
- `argv[0]` through to `argv[argc-1]` are pointers to strings whose meaning will be determined by the program.
- `argv[0]` will be a string containing the program's name or a null string if that is not available. Remaining elements of argv represent the arguments supplied to the program. In cases where there is only support for single-case characters, the contents of these strings will be supplied to the program in lower-case.

As such, you are passing in `argv[argc]` (which is a null pointer) to `strcmp`.